# Wiring two light fixtures on a switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I am having trouble wiring two lights on one switch, I have tried configuring in parallel and in series but the second light never works (I tried switching the fixtures to make sure that wasn't the issue). I am taking the 14/2 wire that is coming from the switch and wiring it as in the photo attached.

[image]

Not sure if it makes a difference, but I pulled power for the switch from an outlet by connecting my switch to the black and white wires at to the outlet.

Thanks!

Comment: both lamps in the diagram should light ... maybe your connections are not the same ... maybe the cable is bad between the two lamps

Comment: Either your work does not actually match the diagram, or there is a defect in it. This should work. We need photos of the work as executed.

Comment: Don't even try to wire them in series.

Answer (score 6):

Your wiring diagram is correct and the lights should work. Since you've switched the fixtures and both worked in the first position, then the problem has to be in the wiring between the first and second light. Re check/re do the wire nut connections in the first junction box. Also check for continuity in the wires between the two junction boxes to verify there's no break in the cable.

Comment: You're totally right! One of the connections had gotten loose. Thanks for confirming the configuration! I tried it in both parallel and series and I must have had a loose connection both times!

Answer (score 4):

The diagram is correct and you've obviously done something right since the first light turns on.

Other things to check:

- Is everything wire-nutted tightly with no loose wires?
- Are you testing with a known working lightbulb?
- Maybe the fixture or bulb socket is bad
- Wire continuity; you might have a break in the line from the first to the second bulb

Comment: You're totally right! One of the connections had gotten loose. Thanks for confirming the configuration! I tried it in both parallel and series and I must have had a loose connection both times!

Comment: @ElenaFerro I'm glad you found the issue. However, it terrifies me to know that one of your connections was loose; this tells me that you might have just gotten lucky with the other connections and they are an arc fire waiting to happen. If using wire nuts then make sure to perform a good pull test to make sure you're twisting  hard enough.